# How to refactor this Enum in java

Tags: java, enums, refactoring

I have a enum to hold the outcome of a rule:

```
enum Outcome{
    PASSED,
    FAILED;
}
```

Now I need to add reasons why the rule failed to the Outcome I return. How can I refactor this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: You could make Outcome a regular class with two fields: a OutcomeType (enum, with constants PASSED and FAILED), and a reason (string)

Comment: since there could be more than one reason to fail,then makes not much sense to refactor the enum...

Comment: An enum can certainly hold a reason field. Why would you not want it to be an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "Outcome" you return must be an enum Type and you know at compile time all the reasons why failure might occur, then you can define a failure token for each type.  For dynamic failure messages, failure reasons that can only be known at run time, I would go with Jay Schauer / JBNizet's comment-solution and make a separate class with members for the pass/fail token and the message string.

```
enum Outcome {
    PASS("Congratulations"),
    FAIL_BLANK("too many blank stares"),
    FAIL_RED("too many Red Herrings"),
    FAIL_NET("network issues");

    private String msg;
    private Outcome(String message) {
       msg = message;
    }

    public String getMsg() { return msg; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I like @JBNizet 's answer better, so here is an implementation

```
public class Outcome {
    public enum OutcomeOptions {
        PASSED, FAILED;
    }
    private final OutcomeOptions outcome;
    private final String message;
    public Outcome(OutcomeOptions outcome, String message) {
        this.outcome = outcome;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public OutcomeOptions getOutcome() {
        return outcome;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I have to return multiple outcomes which failed for different reasons? Outcome.FAILED references same object

Comment: this looks better to me. I need to return a list of failure reasons.